# Html to pdf with images using hiqpdf

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, hiqpdf

I am converting a html with images and css files using `HiQPdf 8.0`. I have done it lots of times in `MVC 4`. Now I am working under `MVC 5` and `HiQPdf 8.0` and the problem is `HiQPdf 8.0` is not loadin external files like css files and images. I solved the issue with css files by writhing the styles in a style tag in the page but do not know how to handle images. Here is my solution:

```
byte[] pdf = RenderPdf(contractId.Value, personId.Value, addressId.Value, transportId.Value, peacockeryNumber, peacockeryDate);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, pdf);

public byte[] RenderPdf(int contractId, int personId, int addressId, int transportId, string peacockeryNumber, string peacockeryDate)
{
    PdfPageViewModel model = new PdfPageViewModel();
    model.Contract = contractRepo.GetContract(contractId);
    model.Person = personRepo.GetPerson(personId);
    model.Supplier = supplierRepo.GetSupplier(model.Contract.SupplierCode, 1);
    model.Customer = customerRepo.GetCustomer(model.Contract.CustomerCode);
    model.Address = customerRepo.GetAddress(addressId);
    model.Transport = transportRepo.Detail(transportId);
    model.Header = settingRepo.GetSetting(Model.Settings.SettingType.Header);
    model.FooterAddress = settingRepo.GetSetting(Model.Settings.SettingType.Address);
    model.Sign = settingRepo.GetSetting(Model.Settings.SettingType.Sign);
    model.Stamp = settingRepo.GetSetting(Model.Settings.SettingType.Stamp);
    model.PeacockeryDate = peacockeryDate;
    model.PeacockeryNumber = peacockeryNumber;
    string htmlToConvert = RenderPdfAsString("HtmlPdf", model);
    String thisPageUrl = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    String baseUrl = thisPageUrl.Substring(0, thisPageUrl.Length - "Home/ConvertThisPageToPdf".Length);
    HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
    htmlToPdfConverter.HiddenHtmlElements = new string[] { "#convertThisPageButtonDiv" };
    byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(htmlToConvert, baseUrl);
    byte[] b = pdfBuffer;
    return b;
}

public string RenderPdfAsString(string viewName, object model)
{
    PdfPageViewModel pdfPage = (PdfPageViewModel)model;
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, null);
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
    ControllerContext,
    viewResult.View,
    new ViewDataDictionary(model),
    new TempDataDictionary(),
    stringWriter
    );
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

And here is the `HtmlPdf` view:

```
<body id="prt-body" style="font-family: 'B Nazanin'">
    <div class="prt-container">
        <header id="prt-header">
            <div id="prt-header-logo">
                <img src="~/Images/logo.png" />
            </div>
            <ul id="prt-header-information">
                <li><span>تاریخ: </span>
                    <label>@Paristan.Broker.UI.Components.PersianDate.GetDate(DateTime.Now)</label></li>
                <li><span>شماره: </span>
                    <label>93323448/1</label></li>
                <li><span>پیوست:</span><label>......................</label></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </header>
        <div id="prt-main">
            <ul id="prt-main-information">
                <li><span>@Model.Person.Title</span><label></label></li>
                <li><span>@Model.Person.Name</span><label></label></li>
                <li><span>@Model.Supplier.Name</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="prt-main-message">@Html.Raw(Model.Header.Value.Replace("#Date", Model.Contract.ContractDate))</div>
            <ul id="prt-main-tables">
                <li>
                    <label>1) مشخصات کالا: </label>
                    <table class="prt-fiveTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>نام محصول</th>
                            <th>گرید</th>
                            <th>تاریخ قرار داد</th>
                            <th>شماره قرار داد</th>
                            <th>شماره قرار داد جز</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Contract.CommercialName</td>
                            <td>@Model.Contract.ProductSymbol</td>
                            <td>@Model.Contract.ContractDate</td>
                            <td>@Model.Contract.ContractNumber</td>
                            <td>@Model.Contract.ComponentNumber</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>2) مشخصات خریدار: </label>
                    <table class="prt-fourTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>نام خریدار</th>
                            <th>کدشناسنامه پتروشیمی</th>
                            <th>کد اقتصاد</th>
                            <th>شماره ثبت / محل ثبت</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.Name</td>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.PetroChemicalCode</td>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.EconomyCode</td>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.RegisterLocation/@Model.Customer.RegisterNumber</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="prt-fourTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>کدشناسنامه ملی</th>
                            <th>کد پستی</th>
                            <th>تلفن</th>
                            <th>نام نماینده / تلفن نماینده</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.CodeMelli</td>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.PostalCode</td>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.PhoneNumber</td>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.DelegacyPhoneNumber/@Model.Customer.DelegacyName</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="prt-twoTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>آدرس</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Customer.Address</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>3) مشخصات قرار داد (ارقام با ریال): </label>
                    <table class="prt-fiveTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>نوع معامله</th>
                            <th>حجم (کیلوگرم)</th>
                            <th>قیمت واحد</th>
                            <th>مبلغ کل خرید</th>
                            <th>کارمزد فروش</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            @{double totalAmount = int.Parse(Model.Contract.Amount) * int.Parse(Model.Contract.Price);
                              double wage = totalAmount * 0.00278;
                              double settlementAmount = totalAmount * 0.99722;
                              double tax = totalAmount * 0.08;}
                            <td>@Model.Contract.ContractType</td>
                            <td>@Model.Contract.Amount</td>
                            <td>@Model.Contract.Price</td>
                            <td>@totalAmount</td>
                            <td>@wage</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="prt-fourTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>مبلغ واریز به حساب فروشنده</th>
                            <th>مالیات بر ارزش افزوده معامله</th>
                            <th>شماره فیش واریزی vat</th>
                            <th>تاریخ فیش واریز vat</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@settlementAmount</td>
                            <td>@tax</td>
                            <td>@Model.PeacockeryNumber</td>
                            <td>@Model.PeacockeryDate</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>4) پیمانکار حمل: </label>
                    <table class="prt-twoTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>نام پیمانکار</th>
                            <th>کد پیمانکار</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Transport.Name</td>
                            <td>@Model.Transport.TransportCode</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>5) آدرس محل تخلیه: </label>
                    <table class="prt-oneTD">
                        <tr>
                            <th>آدرس مقصد (تخلیه)</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Address.EvacuationAddress</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>6) توضیحات: خوانده شده از فایل معاملات </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <footer id="prt-footer">
            <div id="prt-footer-img">
                <img src="Files/Sign/@Model.Sign.Value" />
                <img src="Files/Stamp/@Model.Stamp.Value" />
            </div>
            <div id="prt-footer-address">@Html.Raw(Model.FooterAddress.Value)</div>
        </footer>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But there is some empty boxes instead of the images in the output pdf. Is it `MVC 5` issue with `HiQPdf` or something else is going wrong?

**Update**

I tried it in `MVC 4` and .Net 4 and 4.5 and it is not working any more. I have used from it as the same way before and nothing were wrong but now its not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found some documentation you might enjoy [here](http://www.hiqpdf.com/FAQs.aspx)

> The images and styles are missing from the PDF document generated by
>   converter and the scripts are not executed because these elements are
>   referenced by relative URLs in the HTML code I convert. How can I give
>   a base URL to be used by converter to resolve these elements?
>
> The methods to convert a HTML code of the HtmlToPdf, HtmlToImage and
>   HtmlToSvg classes and the constructors of the PdfHtml and PdfHtmlImage
>   classes have a baseUrl parameter that can be used by the HiQPdf HTML
>   converters to resolve the relative URLs found in the HTML code you
>   convert.
>
> For example, if an image is referenced in the HTML code you convert
>   with  and the image can be accessed from
>   the http://www.example.com/Images/image.png fully qualified URL, then
>   you have to set http://www.example.com/ as base URL in your
>   application code. Similar for the style and script files referenced in
>   the HTML code you convert.

so it looks like youll have to use the fully qualified names to get it to work

Comment: It worked. The base url was incomplete and it was the issue. it was localho while the url was localhost:blah. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I`m adding my code snippet as the accepted answer is solving the issue, but it missing code example. File is located here in asp net core project

**wwwroot/images/logo.png**

c# code

```
        HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Landscape;

        // razor view to string
        string htmlToConvert = await RenderViewHelper.RenderViewAsync(context, "document_chtml", model);

        // add base url to constructor
        byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToMemory(htmlToConvert, $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}");

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=document.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.ContentLength = pdfBuffer.Length;

        return new FileContentResult(pdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
```

Razor code

```
<img alt="logo" src="~/images/logo.png" title="logo"/>
```